# How long does it take to turn aluminum smelters on and off?

Tags: electrochemistry, materials, electrolysis

This may fit better under "engineering," but I figured I'd start here.

Aluminum is produced through an electrolysis process, and [Wikipedia tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_smelting) that the electrolytic cells need constant power in order to operate - that if the aluminum solidifies, you can't just turn the thing back on.

I'm curious as to how long it takes to turn these processes on and off at a commercial aluminum smelting operation. Is it the sort of thing you can start in the morning and turn off in the evening when the plant closes, or do you really want to operate the cells 24-7?

Comment: I'll say you simply don't ever turn it off, as with blast furnaces for producing iron. If you want to stop the thing, you have to dismantle and afterwards rebuild it.